# Generic Type extending an Final Class

Tags: java

In java Final classes can't be extended by normal classes but a generic type can be extended. What does this signify? For example Integer is a final class in JAVA API this class cant be extended but the following code does not show any error.

```
public class SampleClass<T extends Integer> {

// memebers

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Although the code shows no errors, any actual binding of the type parameter `T` will have to be to an `Integer` since, as you correctly note, `Integer` is a `final` class. The generic type parameter, while it uses the `extends` keyword, is not defining an actual class; hence there is no error in the code you posted.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the compiler expects `T` to be of type `Integer` or a type that derives from `Integer`.

Since `Integer` is `final` class, `T` can only be `Integer`.

The error can only happen when you're trying to **create** a type from `Integer`

for example, the compiler will throw an error here:

```
class IncompilableInteger extends Integer { }
```

because it is trying to **create** a type from `Integer`, but this won't:

```
class Compilable <T extends Integer> { }
```

because it is trying to **create** a type that contains object(s) of type - either is an `Integer` or a type that derives from `Integer` but not a different `Integer` by itself.